# annual dates list help

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table of important annual dates. I'd like to display them in a gridview with the date that's coming up to be on top row relative to today's date. For instance, if my birthday is the next thing coming up that should be at the top row of the gridview.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,

rod.

Comment: Will you explain **relative to today's date** a bit?

Comment: If you are looking for an SQL, something like SELECT * FROM YourDatesTable WHERE ImportantDate >= GETDATE ORDER BY ImportantDate DESC might work.

Comment: How are you storing these dates? Do they have a year component?

Comment: @Martin Smith - Right now, I'm storing them in SQL Server table as datetime field. But, design still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an SQL, something like SELECT * FROM YourDatesTable WHERE ImportantDate >= GETDATE ORDER BY ImportantDate DESC might work.